# SQL distance calculated incorrectly

Tags: sql, geolocation

I have this sql statement for calculating distance from longitude and latitude:

```
    SELECT post_id, (((acos(sin(('52.4778044' *pi()/180)) * 
sin((lat *pi()/180))+cos(('52.4778044' *pi()/180)) * 
cos((lat*pi()/180)) * 
cos((('-1.9103284' - lng)*pi()/180)))) 
*180/pi())*60*1.1515) 
as distance FROM wp_offers_latlng ORDER BY distance
```

Although this is mostly working, in a few cases it seems to be throwing out distance values that are much shorter than they should be (it seems to be having particular problems with distances of around 30 - 40 miles being reported as under a mile).

Some typical responses:

```
15168
0.402004443304248

15164
0.402004443304248

15148
0.402004443304248

12972
0.445279823288741
```

Those first three are the supposed distances between locations in two completely seperate cities

I'd appreciate it  if someone could point out any problems in how I have this written.

Comment: Do you have an example, and some results,  of executing this statement directly? The snippet provided looks like it's lifted out of code since it contains `%s` instead of values.

Comment: Your sql query is correct so the lat lng values must be wrong. Please show these values that are producing your output.